# Cluster Fails when Enabling Storage Spaces Direct Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, failovercluster, storage-spaces-direct

I'm trying to get a 2 Node Hyper-converged Fail-over cluster setup with 2016 Server and Storage Spaces Direct.

I am able to Validate (with no errors) and Create the Cluster with the S2D tests included but when I run Enable-S2D on the Cluster the cluster fails.

What I can see happening is that during the S2D setup the Cluster Service begins to restart repeatedly.

On both nodes I get errors

> 7032
>   The Service Control Manager tried to take a corrective action (Restart the service) after the unexpected termination of the Cluster Service service, but this action failed with the following error:
>   The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
>
> 7031
>   The Cluster Service service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this "x" time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 15000 milliseconds: Restart the service.
>
> 7024
>   The Cluster Service service terminated with the following service-specific error:
>   The cluster join operation was aborted.

As well as Application Event 1000

> Faulting application name: clussvc.exe, version: 10.0.14393.2273, time stamp: 0x5ae40d1f
>   Faulting module name: clussvc.exe, version: 10.0.14393.2273, time stamp: 0x5ae40d1f
>   Exception code: 0xc0000409
>   Fault offset: 0x00000000000332f1
>   Faulting process id: 0x16d0
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d3ef1c502ea68c
>   Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\Cluster\clussvc.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\Cluster\clussvc.exe
>   Report Id: a1700bc1-bf18-464e-b35c-b759832e1382
>   Faulting package full name:
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

I've Destroyed and recreated the cluster several times but no luck.

My drives are all clean and have "CanPool = True". I have a file-share witness configured and validated.

Comment: You might want to remove your drives from S2D pool, wipe them off to get rid of metadata and add back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an update,

After looking around found another post that Failover-Clustering/S2D nodes can not have Domain Controllers installed on them.

[Storage spaces direct Enable-ClusterStorageSpacesDirect returns with error Failed to start health providers](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/95955d78-ad97-48e9-ba05-b4595b3219b8/storage-spaces-direct-enableclusterstoragespacesdirect-returns-with-error-failed-to-start-health?forum=WinServerPreview)

I could not find any other supporting information on this claim. (If anyone can find a reference as to why I would appreciate it.)

However, after cleaning the disks and re-initializing the storage and receiving the same errors I removed the ADDS from the Nodes and was then able to successfully configure S2D and Fail-over Clustering.

I think at one point I had actually believed that this was the case, that a DC could not be on a host node.

Sounds like few people like S2D with only 2 nodes so I will look in to a replacement option for the future.

I appreciate your help and recomendations.

Comment: Thanks for your update! I totally missed DC part. Never mix DC with anything else, and always go virtualized.

Answer (score 5):

Don’t do S2D with only two nodes as it’s nothing but begging for troubles! Failover isn’t reliable and you can’t lose second node (obviously!) or second disk/ssd in a row. In RL it means your cluster will collapse with a very high probability during patch process and you’ll have hard times getting your data back... In your particular case you have to re-create S2D pool, create virtual disk and only after you have working shared storage you start playing with f/o cluster thing.

Comment: This is true! Anything below 4 nodes is barely usable with S2D.

Comment: Is it possible to enable S2D before creating a Cluster? I thought the cluster had to be created first for S2D to create the pool.

Answer (score 5):

Plus one for not to use S2D with two nodes. Starting from poor reliability and ending with short features list in such scenario. There are a lot of topics with comparing S2D with any other solutions, but this one is my favorite.
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1445491-s2d-vs-starwind-virtual-san 
For two nodes you can take a look at something like HP Storevirtual (but AFAIR right now it's on EOL stage) https://h20392.www2.hpe.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=VSA1TB-S or Starwind which is basically free with its features. https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san

Comment: Unfortunately my storage is larger than is allowed for the free version for either product.

Comment: There’s no capacity limitation within free version of StarWind.

Comment: Is there a specific version or Edition that's free? I see the Standard that handles up to 4TB and then the Enterprise and Data-center that are unlimited.

Comment: I guess StarWind Virtual SAN Free is what you're looking for. https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free